# How to weaponise Anti-Gravity?

Tags: science-based, weapons, gravity, military, modified-gravity

**Antigravity**, as a recap, is the phenomenon of creating a field that is free of / opposes normal gravity.

Supposedly Antigravity is real and can be created. The most common idea is to have a rotating superconductor (*this follows supersymmetric gravity, where the two go hand in hand*). Let's imagine that works too.

I have seen common applications be floating cards, real hover-boards, and probably some rocket propellers.

But I wonder how anti-gravity can be used for more... military aspects. I am not just talking about military vehicles, but more focused on the weapons themselves, like guns, melee and missiles. How could anti-gravity improve these aspects?

Comment: Does this anti-gravity applies only to gravity, or acceleration as well?

Comment: I think it affects both.

Comment: We would need a LOT more info on this fictional Anti-Gravity of yours, to be able to apply the "science-based" tag answers. How does it work, range of effect, power usage, persistence of effect, what means are utilized to prevent the universe from imploding, etc..

Comment: There are at least  two distinctly different concepts about 'anti'gravity'. One concept is about reversing gravity, so that you end up with a repulsive force. Things actively push away from each other. (Opposite relativistic effects? Time contraction?) The second is to 'nullify' gravity, so that there are no gravitational effects at all. No push, no pull, and perhaps no relativistic effects (time dilaation, for instance). Which concept are you envisioning?

Comment: Also, are you manipulating gravity, or the Higgs Field and mass? If you have a 'mass manipulator' that allows one to manipulate inertia, it might look like 'anti-gravity' but would be based on a completely different physical factor. One could, for instance, propel a 50 ton 'mass' with just one hand, if inertia could be 'violated' and the object were given the inertia of a pebble.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second from the OP's answer it appears like inertia nullification is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the antigravity works, especially its range and directionality. It also depends on which laws of physics you intend to break or retain.

If it has a long range and is directional then placing such an object in a deep mine on Earth could cause mayhem. Large quantities of rock could be projected high into the air only to eventually come crashing back down hundreds or even thousands of miles away when they escaped the influence of the device.

With careful calculation they could probably be aimed at cities.

Comment: I like this answer because it does not immediately jump to Silver Age of Comics-style extremes, and instead focuses on more human-scale applications. FTL and messing with black holes and blowing up planets still requires huge amounts of energy, but levitating some rocks or screwing with a few buildings are well within what modern industry and militaries can manage, if the energy scales similarly to what we already have. But of course, it depends on precisely how the antigravity works.

Answer (score 1):

**Gravity is a weapon**

With gravity, you can toss something into space or squash it like a bug.

[image]

See the [gravity gun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZSdrBTNOA8) from Gantz: 0

Enough gravity you can create a black hole singularity super weapon.

For personal use, you can have inertial dampeners which would allows ships to accelerate faster without the G-forces harming the occupants. Armour which allows a person to take a blow without killing the wearing inside.

Gravity has a multitude of uses.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas, that may depend on how you manipulate gravity, are

1. Gravity cannon, using gravitational fields to accelerate projectiles producing results akin to railguns.
2. gravitational shielding, if you have a strong gravitation field that points away from yous spacecrafts then it would repel what ever hits it. If strong enough it would repel light weapons and look like a mirrored bubble.
3. if operates by distorting space time then as Abyssfire X points out if would allow your
   spacecrafts to travel FTL, by creating Alcubierre warp drive bubble around it. it would also be able to use these bubbles as weapons as the bubbles can be [destructive to what they hit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive#Damaging_effect_on_destination)
4. they could also create wormholes for either transport (either of themselves or of weapons),  or if the other end is in the core of a star (for example) then they would have a massive plasma cannon, they could also form the output end of the wormhole inside an enemy spacecraft, space station, ect, which would cause mild damage.
5. they could also use black holes as matter storage, using anti gravity to move it, and contain its affects. They could then use antigravity to remove mass that they require, for fabricating guns, projectiles, drones...

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

#### Make the Death Star look like a water pistol

If gravity creates black holes from mass-energy. Then anti-gravity can convert black holes into mass-energy.

By stopping the effect of gravity in that point-mass your black holes contents will instantly "become" regular matter again. With matter essentially co-located in space you've achieved perfect fusion with every atom. You've got a fusion bomb with fusable mass equivalent to all the matter that was sucked in. $E = mc^2$ but m is the mass of everything it's ever eaten.

You can use your anti gravity weapon to direct the black hole towards your enemy, and then turn off its gravity. 20 years later when the supernova has died down, you can harvest any useful atoms from the debris field.

Answer (score 1):

The anti-gravity applied in large scale can be a weapon by itself:

1. **Any building would be immediatly destroyed or heavily damaged**. Most building rely on gravity (i.e. weight of construction blocks) to be stable. Removing the weight would case all deformations to act like springs that pushes all building apart.
2. To move we need to push the earth. Antigravity would immediatly **immobilize any humans and vehicles** wich has no specially designed rocket/jet propulsion. Even planes would have hard time with stable flying (aplies mostly for heavy planes, fighters would only have some little inconvinience).
3. While it can be seemes possible to move through air using firearms as rockets, but it is a very bad idea. Their impulse is directed far from center of mass (and can't be with needed accuracy) - so it would just make shooters spin wildly. **So no shooting will be possible**. Even first round would most probably miss, since all aiming contraptions are designed with constant gravity in mind.
4. After antigravity is switched off - **the fall could kill them**

To summurise: antigravity is by itself a perfect suppression weapon with some great destriction potential.

Comment: "Their first shot took out our artificial gravity. I found myself weightless and unable to function." — [ST6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country) (First thing that came to my mind when I read the question's title.)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the range, power, and precision you can get to. You can use the gravity to just spam black holes everywhere that you want to get rid of if you had enough power. Using range, you could just set mines that just blow tons of earth and stone into the air and then manipulate it to come back down on a specific spot. And if you don't fell like polluting the universe with black holes, you could just use precision to create an antigravity field that varies across a whole ship, replicating the effect of negative mass and ripping the ship apart. There is a whole range of possibilities in mass-destruction weapons.

On a smaller scale, however, you could create inertial dampeners to nullify the effect of G-forces on the occupants of a ship, enabling FTL travel which would advance logistics, and armor that reflects force and matter alike to provide an absolute defense.